# Ruby - Ajax: update session value when clicking on a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session

I have this ruby function in a controller

```
def updateSession value
   case value
   when 1,2
     session[:value]=1
   when 3,4
     session[:value]=2
   end
end
```

And I have different links that redirect to different pages.
I would like to change the session value when clicking on those links by calling the updateSession function

Is it possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a route for:

```
map.update_session 'update_session', :controller => "session", :action => "update"
```

Then I assume you're trying to get "value" from user parameters, so you could use the following to generate your links:

```
<%= link_to "Update Session - 1", update_session_path(:value => 1) %>
```

Then add the following to your controller to act based on the params provided:

```
def update_session
  value = params[:value].to_i
  case value
  when 1,2
    session[:value] = 1
  when 3,4
    session[:value] = 2
  end
end
```

Comment: ty that works fine, but is there a way to hide the url in the status and address bar. Cause when the user put his mouse over the link he can see the address, copy/paste it and change the parameter value. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I'm nearly 3 years late commenting, but I had to say this: your action should not allow a user to submit a parameter that is illegal. Simply hiding the parameters is not sufficient security. If you want to hide the params simply to make it look nice, consider calling your action with javascript that is triggered by clicking on your link.